# Замена определенных слов на вводимые пользователем

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
fws = '''The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was
unaffected by these events.'''

fws = fws.split()

for spec_words in fws:
    if spec_words.lower() == 'adjective':
        spec_words = spec_words.replace(spec_words.lower(), input('Enter an adjective'))
    elif spec_words.lower() == 'noun':
        spec_words = spec_words.replace(spec_words.lower(), input('Enter a noun:'))
    elif spec_words.lower() == 'verb':
        spec_words = spec_words.replace(spec_words.lower(), input('Enter a verb:'))
    elif spec_words.lower() == 'adverb':
        spec_words = spec_words.replace(spec_words.lower(), input('Enter an adverb:'))
```

Этот код должен менять слова на вводимые пользователем. Но вместо того чтобы запросить ввод на замену каждого слова он пишет:

```
Enter an adjective:Handsome
Enter a noun:Moon
Enter a noun:Moon

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Я так понял, это потому что NOUN встречается в предложении 2 раза,
но если заменить NOUN на ADVERB (например), то просит ввести только:

```
Enter an adjective:adj
Enter a noun:noun
Enter an adverb:adv

Process finished with exit code 0
```

И пропускает VERB.

Мне нужно чтобы заменялось NOUN/VERB/ADJECTIVE/ADVERB на одно слово (если NOUN/VERB/ADJECTIVE/ADVERB встречаются несколько раз) и выводило на экран модифицированное предложение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае **VERB** не заменялся ибо при `split`'е он оставался с точкой, а в цикле Вы искали просто **verb**.

Вот мой вариант решения данной задачи, используя модуль регулярок.

```
import re
fws = """The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. 
A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events."""

fws_lower = fws.lower()

if 'adjective' in fws_lower:
    fws = re.sub('adjective', input('Enter an adjective: '), fws, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if 'noun' in fws_lower:
    fws = re.sub('noun', input('Enter a noun: '), fws, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if 'verb' in fws_lower:
    fws = re.sub('verb', input('Enter a verb: '), fws, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

print(fws)
```

Comment: Думаю, смысла на каждое условие приводить к нижнему регистра нет `fws.lower()`, лучше заведите переменную для этого и ее в условиях подставляйте

Comment: А если в тексте есть слова noun, verb, adjective изначально в нижнем регистре, которые не нужно заменять?

Comment: @insolor проверять надо сразу в верхнем регистре, без `fws_lower`, заменять тоже верхний регистр и убрать флаг `flags=re.IGNORECASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Создаем и записывам текст в файл *madlibs.txt* необязатльная часть (в задаче не было сказано, но так надежнее на мой взгляд):

```
import re

with open('madlibs.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(
        "The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB.\nA nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events.")

text = ''
with open('madlibs.txt', 'r+') as file:
    text = file.read()           # запись текста из файл madlibs.txt в переменую
    for change in re.compile(r"ADJECTIVE|NOUN|VERB|ADVERB").findall(text): 
        text_input = input("Enter %s\n" % change) # Пользовательский ввод хотел попробывать %s
        text = text.replace(change, text_input)   # Замена текста на введенный

with open('madlibs.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(text)   # перезапись получившегося текста в файл 

with open('madlibs.txt', 'r') as file:
    print(file.read()) # чтение из файла
```

---

PS `with open` эта конструкция позволяет не писать каждый раз `close()`, хотел попробывать!